# URL Rewrite using htaccess for one variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My url is

```
domain.com/?p=slide&op=1
```

here i rewrite domain.com/slide using

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
```

I don't want to rewrite op=1, it should work when i enter

```
domain.com/slide?op=1
```

Any help would be appreciated!.

Comment: When this URI is entered: `domain.com/slide?op=1` you want it to be mapped silently to `domain.com/?p=slide&op=1` ¿Is that right?

Comment: nope, the link is domain.com/slide, so i want domain.com/slide?op=1 when i click link, i add some get function in the op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
```

Will make it so that any query string is kept and appended to the new URL.

Comment: I already tried that link, but i can't understand from that. Can you please explain that ?

Comment: @user1619228 It just means that it will take the query string and append it.  `blah?foo=bar&baz=boo` becomes `index.php?p=blah&foo=bar&baz=boo`.

Comment: i used this one :
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]. but my css & js is not working.. any help ?

Comment: @user1619228 So are you trying to preserve the `op` part? Or is the rewrite not working to begin with?  If you go to `/slide` does it behave as desired?